# Running java program in windows cmd. Passing string arg

Tags: java

Hey, this is probably a simple question, but I am having trouble running my java program from command line. I have 3 java files that I compiled and now I have 3 class files in a directory. I want to run them and pass a string parameter to my main.

Code Sample:

```
package dfa;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DFA myDFA = new DFA();

    run(myDFA, args);
}

public static void run(DFA myDFA, String[] args)
{
    String test = args[0];
    if(myDFA.accept(test))
        System.out.println("yes");
    else
        System.out.println("no");
}
}
```

How I am running it:

```
java -classpath . Main.class testString
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Main.class
.
.
.
.
Could not find the main class: Main.class
```

New Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dfa/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:dfa.class
....Could not find the main class: dfa.Main
```

Comment: Post the entire class, please.  This will be easy to sort out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `.class` extension when your run java.

`java -classpath . Main testString` is enough if you class is in the default package.

---

> By default, the first non-option argument is *the name of the class* to be invoked. A *fully-qualified class name* should be used.

It means that if your class is in a package you have to use `java my.package.project.Main`

In your case :

```
java -classpath . dfa.Main testString
```

To execute this command you must be in the parent folder of dfa directory.

---

**Resources :**

- [Java documentation for Unix](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)
- [Java documentation for Windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: Rather "you *shouldn't* put the `.class` extension".

Comment: @Colin Thanks, I was no aware that I had to include the package at the front. However, for some reason I am still having the same issue. Do you know of anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: I posted the newest error message. To get this error, I inputted java -classpath . dfa.Main testString

Comment: To execute this command you must be in the parent folder of dfa directory.

Comment: ..and thus not inside the dfa folder or somewhere else.

Comment: Aha! Thanks guys. I really appreciate the help. I swear I am not this helpless most of the time. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
java -classpath . dfa.Main testString
```

The name of your class must be the fully resolved class name, including the package.